# How to get multi tables records in PHP using SQL Server?

Tags: php, pagination

How to get 20 records 20 to 30 from three table in PHP Using SQL Server for pagination purpose bekow are query i am using,One table records has been fetched but other 2 table records not fetch how to fetch multi table records in sql Which is the correct query,my query are as below

**OLD query**

```
select SLNO, T.* 
    from ( 
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Transactionate DESC) AS SLNO , SavingRecurringMst_Kuber.* 
        from SavingRecurringMst_Kuber r, BhishiRegistrationMst b, SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber s 
        where 
            RegID = FKRegID and PkSavingRegID = FKSavinRegID ) as T where 20 >= T.SLNO and 30<= T.SLNO
```

**New query suggested**

```
select
    SLNO,T.FirstName,T.LastName,T.DOB,T.Address,T.TotalAmount,T.TotalAmount 
from 
    ( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Transactionate DESC) AS SLNO , SavingRecurringMst_Kuber.* 
        from 
            SavingRecurringMst_Kuber r, BhishiRegistrationMst b, SavingRegistrationMst_Kuber s 
        where 
            RegID=FKRegID and PkSavingRegID=FKSavinRegID ) as T 
        where 
            T.SLNO >= 20 and T.SLNO <= 30
```

The columns `T.TotalAmount,T.TotalAmount` belong to `SavingRecurringMst_Kuber` and `T.FirstName,T.LastName,T.DOB,T.Address` belongs to `BhishiRegistrationMst`.

Comment: Can you try formatting your question a little?

Comment: You either want JOIN or UNION, research both.